# Adding Collation to a SQL Server CTE statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, collation

I am trying to determine how to add COLLATION to this operation....

```
WITH CTE (srtTxt, DuplicateCount)
AS
(
    SELECT 
       srtTxt,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY srtTxt ORDER BY ID) AS DuplicateCount
    FROM dbo.tblLang
    **WHERE DuplicateCount > 1**
 )
 DELETE
 FROM CTE
 WHERE DuplicateCount > 1
 GO
```

This is the setting I am trying to apply...

```
COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS srtTxt
```

I have tried a variety of changes like this....

```
WITH CTE (srtTxt, DuplicateCount)
AS
(
    SELECT 
       srtTxt,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY srtTxt ORDER BY ID) AS DuplicateCount
    FROM 
       (SELECT srtTxt COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS AS srtTxt
        FROM dbo.tblLang) AS T
       **WHERE DuplicateCount > 1**
 )
 DELETE
 FROM CTE
 WHERE DuplicateCount > 1
 GO
```

Any ideas on how to implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that you are deleting, you don't need to select `srtTxt` other than the partition, so all that is needed is:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY srtTxt COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS 
                         ORDER BY ID) AS DuplicateCount
    FROM dbo.tblLang
 )
 DELETE
 FROM CTE
 WHERE DuplicateCount > 1;
```

However, if you did need to also select the re-collated field, in order to prevent repetition of the collation in the `Select` and Partition, you can DRY this up with a preceding CTE:

```
WITH Collated AS 
( 
   SELECT ID, srtTxt COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS srtTxt
   FROM dbo.tblLang
),
Duplicates(srtTxt, DuplicateCount)
 AS
 (
    SELECT srtTxt,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY srtTxt ORDER BY ID) AS DuplicateCount
    FROM Collated
 )
 DELETE
 FROM Duplicates
 WHERE DuplicateCount > 1;
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2e21a/2)

Comment: Sorry I left off some code please see update OP  WHERE DuplicateCount > 1

Comment: Your original query looked correct - you can't filter by the `row_number` value projected by the windowing function in the same query it is used - the outer filter on the CTE will delete all duplicate rows other than the first.

Comment: Yes I am seeing the problem, fact is I was wanting to add another filter on the SELECT. I can get the ORDER BY to sort by DuplicateCount but it will not apply the WHERE condition. If I add another field, other than ROW_NUMBER, could I then filter with WHERE?

Comment: Another field on the table = Yes, but if was another derived column, aggregate etc, then you would need to pre-project either in another cte or a derived table (similar to the second example with the `collated` prefilter cte).

Answer (score 2):

I see that you missed to select ID in the sub-query
Please add ID too as follows

```
;WITH CTE (srtTxt, DuplicateCount)
AS (
    SELECT 
    srtTxt,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY srtTxt ORDER BY ID) AS DuplicateCount
    FROM (
    SELECT 
    ID, srtTxt COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS AS srtTxt
    FROM dbo.tblLang
    ) AS T
 )
 DELETE
 FROM CTE
 WHERE DuplicateCount > 1
 GO
```

Comment: Sorry I left off some code please see update OP  WHERE DuplicateCount > 1